# jquery when() with animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
    $.when(
        $('#el1').animate({ left: '400px' }, { duration: 1000}),
        $('#el2').animate({ left: '600px' }, { duration: 1000}))
.done(function() { ...}).fail(function(){ ...});
```

I have also event fired asynchronously when user resize browser that stops these animations:

```
$('#el1').stop(true,false);
$('#el2').stop(true,false);
```

So I expected that .`fail()` method should be executed, but it is not and `.done()` method is executed.

Is there a method to somehow force .fail() method?

I know that I can achieve that without using `.when/.done` but I need this and I actually need to understand that.

Comment: Stopping animations is not considered a "failure", hence no fail call.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie perhaps it should be? (unless `skipToEnd` is `true`)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie OK, and is there any way to call fail?

Comment: You only have access to the promise objects. You need the original deferred object used by animations behind the scenes in order to call `reject`. Not sure if that is accessible as it breaks the encapsulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might resolve this (no pun intended) by keeping another promise around that you can `reject` if the `resize` occurs.

```
// promise that will reject on window resize (probably needs to 
// be debounced to prevent multiple calls to .reject)

var completed = $.Deferred();
$(window).on('resize', completed.reject);

// this would be the original code, dependent on both the animations
// **and** the new promise.  As soon as the promise is rejected this
// code *should* drop to .fail immediately (and incidentally stop
// the animations)

$.when($('#el1, #el2'), completed).done(function() {
     ...
}).fail(function() {
    $('#el1, #el2').stop(true, false);
});

// new .when, that only depends on the two animations.  It'll fire
// whether the animations complete or not, but should do nothing if
// the promise was already rejected because of the resize.

$.when($('#el1, #el2')).done(completed.resolve);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ejm7pkzd/